Microsoft Teams payment error: “Rejected. ,[object Object]” when processing payments via third-party apps
I'm facing an issue where customers are unable to make payments through Microsoft Teams. Here's the error message they see:
We can't charge this payment method due to an issue on our end. Try another payment method or contact support and mention error code: Rejected. ,[object Object] (CV: M4JNvCMLrmPAb7vV.0.0)
Steps I’ve Taken to Troubleshoot:

Cleared Teams cache.
Used the new Teams desktop app.
Tried reproducing the issue in browser incognito mode.
Added a different credit card.

Findings:

The issue persists across different environments and with new payment methods.
A support engineer confirmed (Tracking ID: #2410100060001473) that the issue is with the payment gateway for third-party apps in Teams.
I uploaded the HAR file to the portal under Case #2409110040002919 for further investigation.

Additional Context:

Our credit card works perfectly for other purchases within Azure Portal and Admin Center.

This issue has been unresolved for over two months, despite multiple follow-ups.


Does anyone know how to address or bypass this issue with the payment gateway for third-party apps on Microsoft Teams? Any guidance would be much appreciated.


Hi, Can you please provide an update on this? What is causing this error and how to fix?
